How do I access iCloud mail programmatically using Python?
I am working on a Python application where I need to access and retrieve emails from iCloud mail. From some searching there doesn't seem to be any official API provided by iCloud. Is there some other way to do this programmatically?
One possible task for the application could be to list all messages in a mailbox.

Email is managed by 3 protocols: IMAP, SMTP and POP. SMTP is used to send mail, while IMAP and POP are used to get them. IMAP is designed to keep mail on the server, instead of POP that can remove it when you read it.
Those protocols are the reason why iCloud doesn't have an API: You simply need to use those protocols, instead. For example, this for SMTP.
You can find the iCloud information here. It will give you the main information:

Server URL: imap.mail.me.com
Server Port: 993
Require SSL
The username should be your email without the @icloud.com
The password can be generate specially for this app as explained here

In this case, iCloud support IMAP that can be used like this:

import sys
import chilkat

# This example assumes Chilkat Imap to have been previously unlocked.
# See Unlock Imap for sample code.

imap = chilkat.CkImap()

# Connect to the iCloud IMAP Mail Server
imap.put_Ssl(True)
imap.put_Port(993)
success = imap.Connect("imap.mail.me.com")
if (success != True):
   print(imap.lastErrorText())
   sys.exit()

# The username is usually the name part of your iCloud email address 
# (for example, emilyparker, not emilyparker@icloud.com).
success = imap.Login("ICLOUD_USERNAME","ICLOUD_PASSWORD")
if (success != True):
   print(imap.lastErrorText())
   sys.exit()

# Select an IMAP folder/mailbox
success = imap.SelectMailbox("Inbox")
if (success != True):
   print(imap.lastErrorText())
   sys.exit()

# Once the folder/mailbox is selected, the NumMessages property
# will contain the number of emails in the mailbox.
# Loop from 1 to NumMessages to fetch each email by sequence number.

n = imap.get_NumMessages()
bUid = False
for i in range(1,(n)-1):

   # Download the email by sequence number.
   # email is a CkEmail
   email = imap.FetchSingle(i,bUid)
   if (imap.get_LastMethodSuccess() != True):
       print(imap.lastErrorText())
       sys.exit()

   print(str(i) + ": " + email.ck_from())
   print("    " + email.subject())
   print("-")

# Disconnect from the IMAP server.
success = imap.Disconnect()

print("Success.")

# Sample output:

#  1: iCloud <noreply@email.apple.com>
#      Welcome to iCloud Mail.
#  -
#  2: "Chilkat Software" <support@chilkatsoft.com>
#      This is a test
#  -
#  Success.


Source from here

Typos/g-mistakes: "generate"[+d] + "support"[+s].

Is it safe to use password like this, specifically for the Apple service, isn't there any other way to do this like token authentication like oauth in Gmail APIs

@pl-jay as explained in my answer, you can generate password specific for this app, there is a way to do it in the Apple help center
